# EPiServer 7: Load CSS in custom DOJO modules

Tags: dojo, episerver

So, I am making this custom module for the user interface in the editor mode.
Since there seems to be little documentation on this; I have a question about the css.

How do you load custom css for the module? Right now I'm loading it and add the css file via JavaScript to the `<head>` tag on `postCreate`. Is this a good way to do this? Or should you keep it inline?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to implement your EPiServer extension as a Shell module or even better as an add-on (which is also Shell module, but can be easily distributed/installed/upgraded/managed in the EPiServer Add-on system.).
In this case it’s extremely easy. You can define your CSS resources and require them for your client module in your module.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<module >

  <!--...Omitted module.config configuration...-->

  <clientResources>
    <add name="myStyles" path="ClientResources/Styles.css" resourceType="Style"/>
  </clientResources>

  <clientModule>
    <requiredResources>
      <add name="myStyles" />
    </requiredResources>
  </clientModule>

</module>
```

Here you define that your module contains styles in Styles.css file that resides in the ClientResources subfolder inside your module/add-on directory. And then you require that resource by name, so the system will load that file for your client side module automatically.
That was the easiest way. Please [download Sample add-on for EPiServer 7 CMS](http://world.episerver.com/Download/Items/EPiServer-CMS/EPiServer-7---CMS/EPiServer-7---Sample-Add-on-Package-and-Source-Code/), it contains source code and more examples.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to simply *require* the stylesheet in your widget:

```
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'xstyle/css!./relative/to/widget/folder/mystyles.css'], function(declare) {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, xstyle already ships with EPiServer 7.5+.